# TokenStream doesn't exist in ANTLR parser C# implementation

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

I'm currently following the "Building a Translator with a Listener" tutorial of "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference", but I'm using C# and translate the examples into that.

However, I got stuck at a variable declaration of the type "TokenStream" which I seem to be missing in C# (I can't find it anywhere). The tutorials Java code says

```
TokenStream tokens = parser.getTokenStream();
```

Beyond the missing TokenStream type in C#, I can't even find an equivalent method of the Parser class.
How is this done with the C# implementation of ANTLR?

Comment: [This example](http://programming-pages.com/2013/12/14/antlr-4-with-c-and-visual-studio-2012/) suggests it's called CommonTokenStream for C#.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: I thought so too, but two things say `CommonTokenStream` is not what I need: theres no method in the parser class which would return me an instance of that, and in the Java example, CommonTokenStream is also referenced shortly after, in the main programs method, as seen in the example you linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably [`ITokenStream`](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4.Runtime/ITokenStream.cs).

AFAIK, the ANTLR4 Java and C# runtime libraries are pretty much the same except that C#'s interfaces have an `I` in front of them, and the C# runtime (obviously) follows the C# naming conventions (method names start with an upper case, etc.).

Comment: That sounds about right. It has the methods called in the tutorial afterwards. But yet the parser object doesn't provide a "getTokenStream" equivalent to get the token stream at all :/

Comment: @DebugErr It's either the `TokenStream` or `InputStream` property instead of a method.

Comment: @280Z28 I thought so too. Theres no TokenStream property. InputStream is of type IIntStream (whatever that is?), but I was able to cast that. Case solved :)

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble using the CommonTokenStream class in Antlr 4.7.2 for C#.

I needed to add a declaration to the top of my Listener class:

```
using Antlr4.Runtime;
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Your answer adds very little to the original question and the comments given.